# How to solve this look up failed for data source in serial context Error?

Tags: java, jsp

Can't solve look up failed for data source in serial context Error in java with Netbeans IDE 7.0.

Error Info :

```
> SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/HRS' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/HRS' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jdbc/HRS} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: HRS not found]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at BeanDir.sConnectionPool.getConnection(sConnectionPool.java:97)
    at org.apache.jsp.candidateform_jsp._jspService(candidateform_jsp.java:162)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/HRS' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jdbc/HRS} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: HRS not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: HRS not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: You mind showing us some code where you are making the actual look up? And also information about which server you are using would be useful. Please edit your question and add at least this information.

Comment: @Paulus: stacktrace tells that OP is using Glassfish 3.x.